# Predicate for many to many relationships not containing entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have 2 many to many relationships between the same entities:

```
Document <<-->> Code  // As documents
Document <<-->> Code  // As preattachedToDocuments
```

And I have two core data fetches that get opposite sets of Codes as results. The first one works, however the second returns no results:

```
// Gives desired results
// Desired: Set of all codes that are attached to the document
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN documents || %@ IN preattachedToDocuments", _document, _document];

// Gives no results
// Desired: Set of all codes not attached to the document
[NSpredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%@ IN documents || %@ IN preattachedToDocuments)", _document, _document];
```

The document itself might be empty at the time of this fetch and lacks any identifying attribute or id. What predicate can I use to give all codes that are not currently attached to the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(documents, $doc, $doc == %@).@count == 0) && (SUBQUERY(preattachedToDocuments, $att, $att == %@).@count == 0)", _document, _document];
```

Comment: Yes! I had started to look at using subquery after posting the question but had a hard time wrapping my head around it. This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think what you want is it should be in documents but not in prefettched documents.

```
[NSpredicate predicateWithFormat:@" %@ IN documents &&(NOT %@ IN preattachedToDocuments)", _document, _document];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Misha, thanks for posting a possible solution but its not quite what I was looking for. I needed all entities that lacked any connection to the document. That said, I did try your example with it having both IN arguments NOT'ed and it still yielded no results. In the end Pdasdf's solution got the job done with SUBQUERY! Thanks again for posting a possible answer.